# deconvolution (convTranspose2D) intialization with bilinear interpolation in pytorch?

Tags: deconvolution

I am running PyTorch implementation of this article (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03650.pdf).

In the article, it says to initialize the deconv layers with bilinear interpolation which is not in the code. it is told that if in deconvolution, we are scaling the data by factor S, the initial weights are defined as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFweu.png)

Does anyone know how can I implement it?

This is the neural network model designed based on the article:

In another word, I don't know how to initialization the deconvolution layers (for example deconv1 layer in this code).

```py
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import numpy as np 
    import torchvision
    import torch.nn.functional as F

    cfg = [64, 128, 256, 512, 512]

    class Deep3d(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, in_channels=3, out_channels=3, device=torch.device('cpu')):
            super(Deep3d, self).__init__()
            self.device = device
            vgg16 = torchvision.models.vgg16_bn(pretrained=True)
            modules = []
            layer = []
            for l in vgg16.features:
                if isinstance(l, nn.MaxPool2d):
                    layer.append(l)
                    modules.append(layer)
                    layer = []
                else:
                    layer.append(l)

            scale = 1
            deconv = []
            layer = []
            for m in range(len(modules)):
                layer.append(nn.Conv2d(cfg[m], cfg[m], kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=True))
                layer.append(nn.ReLU(inplace=True))

                layer.append(nn.Conv2d(cfg[m], cfg[m], kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=True))
                layer.append(nn.ReLU(inplace=True))

                if(m==0):
                    layer.append(nn.ConvTranspose2d(cfg[m], 65, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=(0,0)))

                else:
                    scale *=2
                    layer.append(nn.ConvTranspose2d(cfg[m], 65, kernel_size=scale*2, stride=scale, padding=(scale//2, scale//2)))


                deconv.append(layer)           # add blocks of layers to deconv part of the network
                layer = []

            self.module_1 = nn.Sequential(*modules[0])
            self.module_2 = nn.Sequential(*modules[1])
            self.module_3 = nn.Sequential(*modules[2])
            self.module_4 = nn.Sequential(*modules[3])
            self.module_5 = nn.Sequential(*modules[4])

            self.deconv_1 = nn.Sequential(*deconv[0])
            self.deconv_2 = nn.Sequential(*deconv[1])
            self.deconv_3 = nn.Sequential(*deconv[2])
            self.deconv_4 = nn.Sequential(*deconv[3])
            self.deconv_5 = nn.Sequential(*deconv[4])

            self.linear_module = nn.Sequential(*[nn.Linear(15360,4096),          # hyperparam choice
                                                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                                                nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
                                                nn.Linear(4096,1950)])          # 1950=65(disparity range)*10*3(10*3 is feature map size)


            self.deconv_6 = nn.Sequential(*[nn.ConvTranspose2d(65,65,kernel_size=scale*2,stride=scale,padding=(scale//2,scale//2))])

            self.upconv_final = nn.Sequential(*[nn.ConvTranspose2d(65,65,kernel_size=(4,4),stride=2,padding=(1,1)),
                                                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                                                nn.Conv2d(65,65,kernel_size=(3,3),stride=1,padding=(1,1)),
                                                nn.Softmax(dim=1)])

            for block in [self.deconv_1,self.deconv_2,self.deconv_3,self.deconv_4,self.deconv_5,self.deconv_6,self.linear_module,self.upconv_final]:
                for m in block:
                    if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                        nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight, mode='fan_out', nonlinearity='relu')
                        if m.bias is not None:
                            nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
                    elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
                        nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
                        nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
                    elif isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
                        nn.init.normal_(m.weight, 0, 0.01)
                        nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)


        def forward(self, orig_x, x):

            x_copy = orig_x
            pred = []
            out_1 = self.module_1(x)
            out_2 = self.module_2(out_1)
            out_3 = self.module_3(out_2)
            out_4 = self.module_4(out_3)
            out_5 = self.module_5(out_4)
            # print(out_5.shape)

            out_5_flatten = out_5.view(x_copy.shape[0],-1)
            out_6 = self.linear_module(out_5_flatten)

            p1 = self.deconv_1(out_1)

            p2 = self.deconv_2(out_2)
            p3 = self.deconv_3(out_3)
            p4 = self.deconv_4(out_4)
            p5 = self.deconv_5(out_5)
            # print(p5.shape)
            p6 = self.deconv_6(out_6.view(x_copy.shape[0],65,3,10))

            pred.append(p1)
            pred.append(p2)
            pred.append(p3)
            pred.append(p4)
            pred.append(p5)
            pred.append(p6)

            out = torch.zeros(pred[0].shape).to(self.device)
            for p in pred:

                out = torch.add(out, p)

            out = self.upconv_final(out)               # to be elt wise multiplied with shifted left views


            out = F.interpolate(out,scale_factor=4,mode='bilinear') # upscale to match left input size


            new_right_image = torch.zeros(x_copy.size()).to(self.device)
            stacked_shifted_view = None
            stacked_out = None
            for depth_map_idx in range(-33,32):
                shifted_input_view = torch.zeros(x_copy.size()).to(self.device)

                if depth_map_idx<0:
                    shifted_input_view[:,:,:,:depth_map_idx] = x_copy[:,:,:,-depth_map_idx:]
                elif depth_map_idx==0:
                    shifted_input_view = x_copy
                else:

                    shifted_input_view[:,:,:,depth_map_idx:] = x_copy[:,:,:,:-depth_map_idx]


                if stacked_shifted_view is None:
                    stacked_shifted_view = shifted_input_view.unsqueeze(1)
                else:
                    stacked_shifted_view = torch.cat((stacked_shifted_view,shifted_input_view.unsqueeze(1)),dim=1)

                if stacked_out is None:
                    stacked_out = out[:,depth_map_idx+33:depth_map_idx+34,:,:].unsqueeze(1)
                else:
                    stacked_out = torch.cat((stacked_out,out[:,depth_map_idx+33:depth_map_idx+34,:,:].unsqueeze(1)),dim=1)

            softmaxed_stacked_shifted_view = stacked_shifted_view

            mult_soft_shift_out = torch.mul(stacked_out,softmaxed_stacked_shifted_view)

            final_rt_image = torch.sum(mult_soft_shift_out,dim=1)

            return final_rt_image





    # if(__name__=='__main__'):
    #     vgg16 = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
    #     model = Deep3d().to(torch.device('cpu'))
    #     out = model(torch.randn(10,3,384,1280),torch.randn(10,3,96,320))
```